# How to create local mirror for ubuntu inside docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, mirror

I wants to create local mirror for Ubuntu inside docker container. Here is the link I am following from git hub. https://github.com/ekino/docker-images

Now the issue is that it is taking too much time to download the whole packages,even though I divided its in part like main,restricted and universe but it is downloading packages of 22 GB. My system is powered on since last 48 hrs but still its not been completed. yes I have enough speed of Internet. But I think its goes in an infinite loop and stuck somewhere.

Is there any other way to accomplish this ? any suggestions ?

Thank you so much in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker container [copy-on-write file system](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon-storage-driver-option) is slow, you want to make sure the data you download gets written to a fast file system. That's what the [VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume) instruction is for in a Dockerfile.

Then to persist that data, you would have to mount that volume on your host file system or use Docker data containers. See [this article](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#volume) for more info on volumes.